# rails sunspot not returning correct results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have a model Foo with an attribute named `listed`.

Now I am running a simple sunspot(solr) query

```
foos = Foo.search do
      with :listed, true
end.results
```

It is returning all foos that have `listed = true` except two of them.

I have already tried the following:

```
Sunspot.remove_all
Foo.solr_index
Sunspot.commit
Foo.all.each(&:index!)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just to add to it. listed is already defined as a searchable field in the model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to init **searchable** in your Foo model

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchable do
    boolean :listed
  end
end
```

then reindex solr

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex
```

or

```
Foo.reindex
Sunspot.commit
```

Comment: Thanks. Of course the filed is already marked as searchable. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used a gem called 'acts_as_paranoid' so that after I delete an object, I can typically recover it. After an object has been destroyed, it stays in the limbo 'deleted' state forever unless I call a command to permanently delete it. That was my problem. Solr Sunspot still has the indices of those deleted items but couldn't retrieve it.

What I did was:

- Permanently delete all of the items in the limbo
- Reindex all objects belong to that Model

Voila! Things are returned correctly.

I happened yesterday and it was even better when the combination of the solr built-in pagination but that's another story.

Hope yours is similar.